# Changing Default UMASK Value

Tags: linux, bashrc

I am attempting to modify the default umask value under all accounts on my linux system to 002. This will hopefully allow both the account and the account's group access to the created files.

I have modified it within /etc/bashrc, however it seems to be making no difference on this default value. The files I create through "File Browser" all have the access rights set to 600.

Is there any error here, as all evidence I can find on the internet points to the bashrc file.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Like its name says, `bashrc` is for the `bash` shell. It's not supposed to affect GUI programs.

The correct place for changing default umask appears to be `/etc/login.defs`.

Comment: Sorry for the slow reply. It appears that the /etc/login.defs modification is still not affecting my GUI applications.

Comment: Apparently its an issue with GNOME / Nautillus. The umask is being set correctly